# How do I write NULL values to the database using drupal_write_record?

Tags: database

I'm using drupal_write_record to update records in the database in Drupal 6, but it appears to skip null values entered into my integer fields and just leave the old value. I've also tried the string "NULL" with no success. Regular integer values work fine.

```
$record = array(
  'id' => ##my_id##,
  'int_field' => null
);
drupal_write_record('my_table_name', $record, array('id'));
```

How can I change 'int_field' back to NULL from an existing value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this patch suite your needs? http://drupal.org/node/227677#comment-4302522